# only sound with .mp4 files in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, mp4, mediaelement.js

I'm using the [mediaelementjs gem](https://github.com/Micka33/mediaelement_rails)  implementing the 2.13.1 version.

Everything works fine in Chrome and Safari. However Firefox will only play the sound when trying to read a .MP4 file.

1. `http://mediaelementjs.com/media/echo-hereweare.mp4` when using this one, the video and
   sound play well (however the [fullscreen button doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764521/mediaelement-fullscreen-bug-with-firefox-and-mp4))
2. `http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4` but when using this one, only the sound play
   and the video won't show up.

My code is very simple:

```js
$(element).html(
    '<video src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" '+
           'width="320" '+
           'height="240"'+
    '</video>'
);
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */);
```

Is this a bug from mediaelementjs or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not support the H.264 codec (usually used in .mp4) natively, it relies on your OS decoders to play it (this currently only works on Windows, and only on Windows 7 or 8). If your OS has no decoders installed it won't play the video at all.

Chrome, IE and Safari include their own H.264 decoders. Firefox doesn't because the H.264 codec isn't royalty-free so Mozilla would have to pay to include a H.264 decoder in Firefox. Furthermore it is against the foundation's open-source philosophy to include a very patented and very non-free (as in freedom) codec in its free and open source browser.

A solution is to provide a flash-based alternative as a fall-back. Another solution is to provide the file in two formats, e.g. H.264 and WebM which covers all large current browsers.

Comment: I am aware of this, this is why I am using [mediaelementjs](http://mediaelementjs.com/), which provide automatically this fallback as well as handling the HTML tags `<audio>`&`<video>` for non-ready browsers.
However sometimes mediaelementjs will work with .MP4 in Firefox, and sometimes not. It looks pretty instable to me, so here is my question: `Is this a bug from mediaelementjs or am I missing something ?`

Comment: My question is more related to [mediaelementjs](http://mediaelementjs.com/) bug than to Firefox not supporting the H.264 codec. However if you know an alternative that would spare me to encode my video files in WebM format and support older browser, I would be happy to know about it. Mediaelementjs actually is the best solution I found.